# Network Solution Domain Name Register Owner Redirect from Old Domain Name URLs to New without Hosting?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

My client want to change his website's domain name. Both old and new domain names are from Network solutions. The current hosting is from hostgator. Once the DNS servers are changed when pointing the new domain name to hostgator, can he still have the old site's url redirected to the appropriate new site url?

I am confused because only the domain name still remains after the domain name change. Can network solution initiate the redirects? or Hostgator has to do it, which mean he needs two separate hosting plan for each site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a way to do it through hostgator's config but you can simply use an htaccess file in the old domain's document root (even if it's the same document root as the new domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Also both old and new domain can be pointed to the same hostgator name server right? and then use domain parking for the old domain.